# Reglar Expression 5 digit number with special character at 3 posistion

Tags: java, regex

I had requirement to validate 5 digit String with - at third position.
For example i want to validate number like these 12-18 ,20-35,40-45.I need java string for the same

Comment: Those are not five digit numbers...

Comment: Are you trying to _generate_ values, or _validate_ existing values? Your question is unclear.

Comment: i am trying to validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
^\d{2}-\d{2}$
```

to match , see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/5x4nUP/1)

Comment: i need to use regular expression for this problem in java.Can you give it in java string format

Comment: final String regex = "^\\d{2}-\\d{2}$";